# When is ##@@@##& more appropriate than ##@@##&?

Tags: syntax, pure-function

When assigning attachment operators, I often run into confusing statements like `##@@##&`, `##@@@##&`, or even `##@@@##&@*##@@##&`. Example:

```
x = ##@@@##&@*##@@##&;

x[{a b, c d}]
(*    {a b, c d}[{a b, c d}[a b, c d][a, b], {a b, c d}[a b, c d][c, d]]    *)
```

Is there a preferred causal order, ontic basis, or at least a post-categorical meta-category for clarifying these unstable lambdas?

Comment: It took me a while :)

Comment: Well, there's always `FullForm`. But if it's your kids who are writing code like that, it means you're not spanking them enough.

Comment: I assume that this is an April 1st joke, but I don't get it.  :(

Comment: @march there were more explanations [in the link given in the original](https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ), but the link was edited away unfortunately.

Comment: @Roman Can't believe I fell for that.  It's 2008 all over again. Luckily, there was an ad that came on first, and I was able to read the video title before the ad was over and click away.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau my kids are only allowed hexadecimal machine code until they're 12.

Comment: I favor that. Although I remain dubious that any kid has ever actually managed to hex a decimal.

Comment: Well, the only day I allowed myself a hearty "##@@@##&@*##@@##&" was when my free Mathematica access was cancelled due to me graduating and leaving the university. (Personally, my favorite grawlix is D[%,#]&/@ for zeroing large linear sums, but YMMV.)

Answer (score 18):

It's a beginner's error to put `@@@` before `@@`:

```
#2~(##2&)~##3&@@##3~#1~#2&@@@{
  Plot[O, r, S, n, a, p],
  DSolve[G, i, r, l!],
  FindFit[S, l, o, w],
  True[G, o, O, f, f],
  Table[i, s!, a!, l, o, l]}
```

It produces the desired output, but eventually Mathematica has a come-back:

> O::argt: O called with 5 arguments; 1 or 2 arguments are expected.

Comment: Snap, that's it! `@@` before `@@@`, except after `/*`. Now I remember, thanks!